# token authorize web api 2 doesn't return userName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using in my project asp.net web api 2, token authorize and when send request to /Token,I receive response

```
{ 
access_token: "u3XOCYV91f2P6odbceNIY_BnkfSpN7gQwzknsRi_.......0iRPlHYNMEES9", 
token_type: "bearer", 
expires_in: 1209599,
}
```

There is no argument UserName =( and when i send the request to the server with token on Authorize ActionResult,everything works well, but User.Identity.Name is null, User.Identity.isAuthenticated = true. Help pls.

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (AuthorizeRepository _repo = new AuthorizeRepository())
            {
                User user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }

 public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),

            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `User.Identity.Name` to be automatically populated, you must add a `ClaimTypes.Name` claim in your access token:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
```